# Looking for a working example of a VS 2022 extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

So I must be doing something wrong. I created a new VSIX project following the wizard and just added the following two lines into the `InitializeAsync` method:

```
Debugger.Launch();
Debugger.Break();
```

My expectation was that when I hit the Debug button and a new VS 2022 instance opens, these lines would be executed and a debugger dialog would be open. Nothing of the kind happens. Breakpoints are not respected, nothing is loaded.

Here is the code:

```
C:\work\VSIXProject1 [master]> tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume OSDisk
Volume serial number is F6C4-7BEF
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   VSIXProject1.sln
│
└───VSIXProject1
    │   source.extension.vsixmanifest
    │   VSIXProject1.csproj
    │   VSIXProject1Package.cs
    │
    └───Properties
            AssemblyInfo.cs

C:\work\VSIXProject1 [master]>
```

**source.extension.vsixmanifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="VSIXProject1.eebd49c5-0e31-4826-9d95-65395a3ebfc4" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Ceridian HCM Inc" />
    <DisplayName>VSIXProject1</DisplayName>
    <Description>Empty VSIX Project.</Description>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0, 18.0)">
      <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
    </InstallationTarget>
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[17.0,18.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
  </Prerequisites>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

**VSIXProject1.csproj**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>17.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <ProjectGuid>{55BEF9E1-29D2-453F-B325-F7787EBE0E04}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>VSIXProject1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>VSIXProject1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <GeneratePkgDefFile>true</GeneratePkgDefFile>
    <UseCodebase>true</UseCodebase>
    <IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>
    <IncludeDebugSymbolsInVSIXContainer>false</IncludeDebugSymbolsInVSIXContainer>
    <IncludeDebugSymbolsInLocalVSIXDeployment>false</IncludeDebugSymbolsInLocalVSIXDeployment>
    <CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>true</CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>
    <CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>true</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram Condition="'$(DevEnvDir)' != ''">$(DevEnvDir)devenv.exe</StartProgram>
    <StartArguments>/rootsuffix Exp</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="VSIXProject1Package.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="source.extension.vsixmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK" Version="17.0.31902.203" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools" Version="17.0.5233" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

**VSIXProject1Package.cs**

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace VSIXProject1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the class that implements the package exposed by this assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>
    /// The minimum requirement for a class to be considered a valid package for Visual Studio
    /// is to implement the IVsPackage interface and register itself with the shell.
    /// This package uses the helper classes defined inside the Managed Package Framework (MPF)
    /// to do it: it derives from the Package class that provides the implementation of the
    /// IVsPackage interface and uses the registration attributes defined in the framework to
    /// register itself and its components with the shell. These attributes tell the pkgdef creation
    /// utility what data to put into .pkgdef file.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// To get loaded into VS, the package must be referred by &lt;Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" ...&gt; in .vsixmanifest file.
    /// </para>
    /// </remarks>
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [Guid(VSIXProject1Package.PackageGuidString)]
    public sealed class VSIXProject1Package : AsyncPackage
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// VSIXProject1Package GUID string.
        /// </summary>
        public const string PackageGuidString = "0595bc43-16f0-4ddc-9d2b-b807258cbe72";

        #region Package Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialization of the package; this method is called right after the package is sited, so this is the place
        /// where you can put all the initialization code that rely on services provided by VisualStudio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token to monitor for initialization cancellation, which can occur when VS is shutting down.</param>
        /// <param name="progress">A provider for progress updates.</param>
        /// <returns>A task representing the async work of package initialization, or an already completed task if there is none. Do not return null from this method.</returns>
        protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
            Debugger.Break();
            // When initialized asynchronously, the current thread may be a background thread at this point.
            // Do any initialization that requires the UI thread after switching to the UI thread.
            await this.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("VSIXProject1")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("VSIXProject1")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Hitting the Debug button opens a new instance of VS 2022 where the new extensions appears to be installed:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your package simply isn't being loaded.  Packages in VS are not loaded until something indicates that they should be; this can either be an explicit call from some other code to tell the VS shell to load your package, or by specifying an automatic loading rule.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/loading-vspackages?view=vs-2022) for details.

Comment: Attributed the class with `    [ProvideAutoLoad("F1536EF8-92EC-443C-9ED7-FDADF150DA82", PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]` and it seems to have worked.